# CSS Filter Multiple URL - Gain Blur and Grayscale At the Same Time

Tags: html, css, blur, grayscale

This are working code for CSS blur filter:

```
filter: blur(3px); -webkit-filter: blur(3px); -moz-filter: blur(3px);
-o-filter: blur(3px); -ms-filter: blur(3px);
filter: url('images/blur.svg#blur');
```

Where blur.sv is:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<filter id="blur">
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" />
</filter>
</svg>
```

And this is working for grayscale:

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
```

But how to i make them grayscale and blur and the same time (especially with the URL)? I tried:

```
filter: blur(3px) grayscale(100%);
-webkit-filter: blur(3px) grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: blur(3px) grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: blur(3px) grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: blur(3px) grayscale(100%);
filter: url('images/blur.svg#blur'), url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
```

but it only gives me the grayscale without blur. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I'd like to make it work in newest major browsers, as stated by Rakesh Juyal it's working fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: This code is working in safari + chrome :  http://jsbin.com/okemik/1

Comment: Thank you. Anyway to make it work in Firefox too?

Comment: Firefox(gecko) supports only .svg format till now. -moz-filter is still not supported. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/filter

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could we possibly use two svg at once? I thought something like "filter: url('images/blur.svg#blur'), url('images/gray.svg#gray');" would work but it didn't :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the working example here:

http://jsbin.com/okemik/6

I made one svg element with blur + grayscale filter:

```
<svg height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="svgBlur" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5"/>
  </filter>

  <filter id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter>

  <filter id='grayscaledBlur'>
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3"/>

    <feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0'/>

    </filter>


</svg>
```